# Load a pixel when clicking a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have indication in my server logs whenever a visitor clicks the submit button on my form.

Therefore I created the class `sub` and placed it in the submission button's DIV:

```
<div id="submit-element" class="form-element sub"><input name="submit" id="submit_form" type="submit" tabindex="8" value="Click Here" /></div>
```

And this is the JS:

```
var loaded=!1;$(".sub").click(function(){loaded||(loaded=!0,$('<img src="/pixel.gif?sub='+loaded+'" width="1" height="1" style="display:none" />').appendTo("body"))})
```

When testing, it seems to work only on my  iPhone Safari, and not my desktop pc - pixel doesn't show in the logs, neither from Chrome or IE.

I don't know whether it is related to the fact that I'm using some JS validator script to make sure that the user entered all required fields in the form before submitting. But either way, I want this pixel to load anyway, even if he didn't entered the required fields.

Edit - Validator Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    $('input,select').bind('focusin focus', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    })

    //Keypress from zipcode and number
    $('[name^=zipcode],[name^=phone]').attr('inputmode','numeric');

    $('[name^=zipcode],[name^=phone]').keypress(validateNumber);
    //alert($(".wc_global_form").innerHeight())
    $("#ouibounce-modal .modal").height($("form.global_form").innerHeight()+38);

    //$("#colorbox").height($("#cboxLoadedContent").height());
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var isTouchDevice = Modernizr.touch || 
(deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/) ||
deviceAgent.match(/(android)/)  || 
deviceAgent.match(/(iemobile)/) || 
deviceAgent.match(/iphone/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipad/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipod/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/blackberry/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/bada/i));
if(isTouchDevice) {
    //$('form[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
}

function checklabel(){
    var windowsize = $(window).width();


if (windowsize < 480) {
    $(".phasepopup .form-wrapper label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.text();
    var eId=label.attr('for');
    label.parent().closest('div').next('div').find('input').attr("placeholder", placeholder );
    label.hide();
    });

    $(".popupform .form-wrapper label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.text();
    var eId=label.attr('for');
    label.parent().closest('div').next('div').find('input').attr("placeholder", placeholder );
    label.hide();
    });

    $("form.innerform .form-wrapper label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.text();
    var eId=label.attr('for');
    label.parent().closest('div').next('div').find('input').attr("placeholder", placeholder );
    label.hide();
    });

}
else{

    $(".phasepopup .form-wrapper label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.text();
    var eId=label.attr('for');
    label.parent().closest('div').next('div').find('input').attr("placeholder", '' );
    label.show();
    });

    $(".popupform .form-wrapper label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.text();
    var eId=label.attr('for');
    label.parent().closest('div').next('div').find('input').attr("placeholder", '' );
    label.show();
    });

    $("form.innerform .form-wrapper label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.text();
    var eId=label.attr('for');
    label.parent().closest('div').next('div').find('input').attr("placeholder", '' );
    label.show();
    });
}

}
    checklabel();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checklabel);

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

            // validate innerform form on keyup and submit
        $(".innerform").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                zipcode: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 5,
                    number: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 10,
                    number: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                service:"required"

            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "firstname required",
                lastname: "lastname required",
                zipcode: {
                    required: "Zipcode required",
                    maxlength: "Zipcode must be 5 digit"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "Phone required",
                    maxlength: "phone must be 10 digits"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email",
                service: "Please select service"
            }
        });

            // validate popupform form on keyup and submit
        $(".popupform").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                zipcode: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 5,
                    number: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 10,
                    number: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                service:"required"

            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "firstname required",
                lastname: "lastname required",
                zipcode: {
                    required: "Zipcode required",
                    maxlength: "Zipcode must be 5 digit"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "Phone required",
                    maxlength: "phone must be 10 digits"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email",
                service: "Please select service"
            }
        });
        //phasepopup


            // validate phasepopup form on keyup and submit
        $(".phasepopup").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                zipcode: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 5,
                    number: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 10,
                    number: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                service:"required"

            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "firstname required",
                lastname: "lastname required",
                zipcode: {
                    required: "Zipcode required",
                    minlength: "Zipcode must be 5 digit"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "Phone required",
                    minlength: "phone must be 10 digits"
                },
                email: "Please enter a valid email",
                service: "Please select service"
            }
        });


});

function validateNumber(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46
        || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
};
```

Comment: I think it could be because the pixel is cached after the first time you tested it, try appending a random parameter to the file name pixel.gif?sub='+loaded+' &v=' +Math.random()+ ...

Comment: can you provide non validated js code?

Comment: You mean `sub='+loaded+'&v=' +Math.random()+" width="1"`? this version doesn't fire the pixel even on my iPhone. Also, I checked the first time I tested, so no way it got cached.

Comment: @misher I update the question to include validator code.

Comment: @rockyraw, try more simple code:
$(".sub").click(function(){$('<img src="/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>').appendTo("body")})

Comment: tried it, didn't help

Comment: Ok, got it working. I tested it on a modal window, and the JS code in the parent page didn't effect the modal one. had to copy code to modal page as well.